# KernelReg performance in a for loop

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a task to fit about 10000 1D profiles obtained from an electron beam to Gaussian.

The raw data is basically very noisy. I had to denoise before fitting. I was advised to use `KernelReg` to do this.

For each profile, I firstly call `KernelReg` and then `lmfit` to extract the center, sigma, amp and offset of raw data in a for loop.

When I tested with 100 profiles:

- If I use only `lmfit` the runtime is 2.4 seconds (cprofiler).
- If I combine `KernelReg` and `lmfit` the runtime is 272 seconds.

The `cprofiler` displays a bottleneck in the `KernelReg` call.

**An example profile:**

```
data_array=np.array([-0.000159229
-0.000213496
-1.37e-05
-0.00021545
1.24e-05
0.000181446
-0.000133793
-7.84e-05
-0.000266477
-0.000206505
-0.000376277
-9.38e-05
0.000174166
-0.000365068
-0.00291559
-6.37e-05
-0.000314041
-0.000426127
-0.000322608
-0.000293555
-0.000306628
-0.000379695
-6.12e-05
-0.000336458
-0.000296795
-6.57e-06
-0.000121408
-0.000327136
-0.000215139
-0.000221265
-0.000112685
-0.000244148
-0.000318746
-0.00039916
-0.00454921
-0.00026823
-0.000153014
-0.000423619
-0.000348621
-0.000311244
-0.000318724
-0.000145046
-0.000164001
-0.000224927
-0.000568133
-0.000106227
-0.00022688
-0.000417715
-0.000382891
2.87e-05
-0.00267422
-0.000207038
-0.000239531
-0.000174655
-0.000145335
-0.000202266
-0.000455647
-0.000348444
-0.000346801
-5.86e-05
-8.12e-05
-0.00016733
-0.000241884
-0.000227368
-0.000229987
-0.000121697
-0.00030503
-0.000244148
7.8e-05
-0.000253847
0.000289293
-0.000123672
0.0175145
-0.000436537
-0.000320966
-0.000177473
-0.000148553
-9.91e-05
-0.000197605
-0.000155855
-0.000259152
-0.000221265
-0.00014023
-8.7e-05
-0.000532443
-7.29e-05
-0.0001464
-0.000401024
-0.000176963
-0.000318946
5.83e-05
-0.000281947
-0.000120476
-0.000313708
-0.000114594
-0.000242483
-0.000162958
-0.000144203
-0.000445903
-1.44e-05
-0.000186307
-0.000197738
8.11e-05
-0.000203264
-0.000407749
0.00026843
-0.000268629
-0.000228789
3e-06
-0.000199136
-0.000201023
1.69e-05
-0.000168995
7.79e-05
6.05e-05
-0.000280038
-0.000305252
-0.000308625
-5.47e-05
-0.00034032
-0.000169572
-0.0001193
-0.000234626
5.73e-05
-0.000235869
8.41e-06
-0.000331353
0.000407483
0.000226658
-4.63e-05
-3.39e-05
-0.000163224
-4.31e-05
-0.000191434
9.93e-05
0.000193032
-9.16e-05
-0.000144513
-0.00010616
-4.39e-05
-5.87e-05
9.19e-06
0.000276642
4.48e-05
-7.63e-05
0.000100678
1.18e-05
0.000209568
0.000472049
0.0291889
0.000433762
0.000433607
0.000574392
0.000997101
0.00142112
0.00391844
0.00768485
0.0138782
0.0216787
0.0281597
0.028893
0.0259644
0.0190644
0.01219
0.00574567
-0.00154854
0.00143113
0.000845396
0.00076789
0.000276753
0.000351285
0.000284233
0.00057053
0.000433873
-0.000197183
1.29e-05
0.000118878
0.000203819
0.000132328
1.84e-05
-4.34e-05
-7.95e-05
-0.000400492
6e-05
-9.98e-05
0.00441493
5.23e-05
-7.08e-05
5.7e-05
-0.000148531
-0.000139475
-3.74e-05
-0.000149086
-0.000234826
-3.42e-05
5.27e-05
-0.000171436
-0.00021778
-0.000175076
-0.000198071
])
position=position = np.linspace(1, 200, 200)
```

**My code:**
This code takes about 1~2 seconds to run a call. It is the bottleneck at run time.

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_regression import KernelReg

data_array_kr = KernelReg(data_array, position,'c')
data_array_pred, data_array_std = data_array_kr.fit(position)
data_array_pred[data_array_pred<0] = 0
```

**Questions:**

- How to improve the performance of my KernelReg call?
- Is this a good choice for denoising and fit using KernelReg+lmfit?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question:

You might try comparing a smoothing algorithm such as Savitzky-Golay (if it can be applied to your data -- it requires samples on a uniform interval).  It definitely takes some time, but might be faster than KernelReg.  You might also try to assess how much smoothing you actually need to get stable fit results.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried Savitzky-Golay filter```from scipy.signal import savgol_filter```, and this works not badly in both runtime performance and smoothing.